# Running Powershell script from C# on windows server

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

I am currently trying to Disable Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration on my Automation software to Open a website on my Windows 2019 server.

I am able to run the Powershell script that edits the registry on the server Manually and from CMD using the same command as i am using to run it from my C# application.

When running the Powershell script from C# i get the output i was meant to receive but the registry has not been changed. I suspect this has something to do with the Execution Policy.

*C#*

```
static void DownloadInstaller()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        info.FileName = "CMD.exe";
        info.Arguments = "/c powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File .\\runIE.ps1";
        info.UseShellExecute = true;
        info.Verb = "runas";
        Process.Start(info);
    }
```

*And this is the Powershell Script i am running*

```
function Disable-InternetExplorerESC {
   $AdminKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}"
   $UserKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}"
   Set-ItemProperty -Path $AdminKey -Name "IsInstalled" -Value 0 -Force
   Set-ItemProperty -Path $UserKey -Name "IsInstalled" -Value 0 -Force
   Stop-Process -Name Explorer -Force -ErrorAction Continue
   Write-Host "IE Enhanced Security Configuration (ESC) has been disabled."
}

Disable-InternetExplorerESC
```

If there is a way to do this from my program in C# i would love to get some help.

Comment: Why not write this using C# and eliminate most if not all of the PowerShell all together?

Comment: Actually went over my head to even think about doing this. I have tried to do this now but cant seem to get it to work. My attmept at this looks like this:
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\", true);
key.OpenSubKey("{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}", true).SetValue("IsInstalled", 0);